# Tesla API (Unofficial) - Testing via cURL

Tags: curl

Before writing any actual code against the Tesla API, I thought I'd hack a few cURL commands to get familiar.  Already struggling.  Just trying to get an oauth token back via:

```
curl -X POST  -H 'Content-Type: application/json' -d '{"grant_type": "password", "client_id": "81527cff06843c838fe1e431c2ef2106796384", "client_secret": "c7257eb71a564034f9419ee651c7d0e5f7aa6bfbd18bafb5c5c033b093bb2fa3", "email": "myemail@email.com","password": "mypassword"}' 'https://owner-api.teslamotors.com/oauth/token'
```

Yields the following error:

```
{"error":"invalid_client","error_description":"Client authentication failed due to unknown client, no client authentication included, or unsupported authentication method."}
```

I suspected maybe the client_id and client_secret shared at https://tesla-api.timdorr.com/api-basics/authentication got revoked, but when I tried signing up for a smartcar account that gave me a different pair, that did not work for me either.

Comment: Unless there's an obvious json formatting issue or blatant curl misuse, I testing this is predicated on having a Tesla account.  I'm not exactly a cURL ninja, so it's completely possible I've just screwed up something basic though.

Comment: I tried to reproduce in postman and get the same error, which seems sane since I'm effectively providing the same input.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, this command works fine as is, I just screwed up the client_id when copy / pasting it.  Leaving up with the corrected version here in case anyone else wants to curl around the Tesla API.

```
curl -X POST  -H 'Content-Type: application/json' -d '{"grant_type": "password", "client_id": "81527cff06843c8634fdc09e8ac0abefb46ac849f38fe1e431c2ef2106796384", "client_secret": "c7257eb71a564034f9419ee651c7d0e5f7aa6bfbd18bafb5c5c033b093bb2fa3", "email": "myemail@email.com","password": "mypassword"}' 'https://owner-api.teslamotors.com/oauth/token'
```

And then using the received token for get queries:

```
curl --request GET --header 'Authorization: Bearer 32819532809859320539205djfdsjfkdsd' 'https://owner-api.teslamotors.com/api/1/vehicles'
```

And then:

```
curl --request GET --header 'Authorization: Bearer 32819532809859320539205djfdsjfkdsd' 'https://owner-api.teslamotors.com/api/1/vehicles/?id=0123456789'
```

Comment: Thanks to this site for the awesome documentation around the web service: https://tesla-api.timdorr.com/

Comment: Do you mind updating this answer according to newest requirements? I believe /oauth/token is depricated

Comment: Sorry, I've completely stopped messing with the API.  So I don't have new examples to drop in.  And unfortunately way to busy to do it for fun.

Answer (score 0):

I wrote these simple python scripts to access the tesla api with the latest requirements which can be used to get anyone started with the api.

https://github.com/Marky0/tesla_api_lite